# radio button php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

I have a problem with the radio button, I can edit and insert but it does not show me anything. what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your help
[image]

radio button

```
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="0"<?php 
                if ($id['visible'] == 0) { echo " checked"; } 
                ?> /> {no}
                &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1"<?php 
                if ($id['visible'] == 1) { echo " checked"; } 
                ?> /> {yes}
```

id

```
enter if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$id=$_POST['id'];
}else{
$id=$_GET['id'];
//echo $id;
} here



@$query  = "SELECT * FROM photographs WHERE id = '$id' ";
    //pokazuje co zostalo zmienione
    echo $query;

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        die("zapytanie sie nie powiodlo");
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? You can't access the value of the radio buttons?

Comment: can you add the output of `var_dump($row)`?

Comment: What is $id['visible]. Where from it?

Comment: mrCode already answered, thank you for your time and answers:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array is `$row` so `$id['visible']` should be changed to `$row['visible']`.

```
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="0"<?php 
                if ($row['visible'] == 0) { echo " checked"; } 
                ?> /> {no}
                &nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="1"<?php 
                if ($row['visible'] == 1) { echo " checked"; } 
                ?> /> {yes}
```

Side note: your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Consider switching to a [Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).